# How can I make reservation control?

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle-apex

```
CREATE TABLE member(
    member_id number(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    member_name varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    member_surname varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    gender varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
    birthdate DATE,
    phone varchar2(11),
    mail varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    member_password varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    address varchar2(255) not null,
    status number(1),
    role_id number(10) NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE reservation(
    reservation_id number(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    member_id number(11) NOT NULL,
    item_id number(11) NOT NULL,
    start_date DATE,
    end_date DATE,
    status number(1),
    isReserved number(1) DEFAULT 0
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE item(
    item_id number(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    member_id number(11) ,
    publish_date DATE,
    is_occupied NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
    publisher_id number(11) NOT NULL
    
);
```

MY TRIGGER WORKS FOR NOW ;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PreInsertreservation
BEFORE INSERT ON reservation
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    
    SELECT status INTO :NEW.status
    FROM member
    WHERE member_id = :NEW.member_id;

    IF :NEW.status != 1 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Error: Member has an inactive status MEMBER . STATUS = 0 ');
    END IF;

    SELECT member_id INTO :NEW.member_id
    FROM item
    WHERE item.member_id = :NEW.member_id;
    
    IF :NEW.member_id IS NOT NULL THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Error: MEMBER NOT NULL ');
    END IF;

    IF :new.start_date >= :new.end_date OR (:new.end_date - :new.start_date)>15 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Error: Start date must be before end date');
    END IF;

    SELECT isReserved INTO :New.isReserved 
    FROM reservation
    Where reservation_id=:NEW.reservation_id;

    IF :NEW.isReserved!=0 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-200001,'Error : The item is already taken another member');
    END IF;
END;
```

If the user reserves an item, the is reserved field will be 1. However, if another user wants to reserve that item and it should not be done between the same dates. Also, if the item is reserved and the person who reserved the item has given up on purchasing the item, after 15 days, the reserved part is 0 again and I need to make it bookable by other users.

Comment: NEw.status is not a variable, it is a psedo row which conatins all the new values, so you rforst statement makes no sense

Comment: You tagged Oracle APEX. I would implement this logic use a validation on the reservation form.